How to setup vite multi-pages react SPA with nested routes on one of the pages?
Here is the vite config, the root index page is an static HTML with no javascript, and the app/index.htm is a react app:
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import { resolve } from "path";
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react";

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  build: {
    rollupOptions: {
      input: {
        main: resolve(__dirname, "index.html"),
        app: resolve(__dirname, "app/index.html"),
      },
    },
  },
});

Inside the app:
import { createBrowserRouter, RouterProvider } from "react-router-dom";
import Page1 from "@/components/page1";
import Page2 from "@/components/page2";
const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "/app",
    element: <App />,
    children: [
      {
        path: "page1",
        element: <Page1 />,
      },
      {
        path: "page2",
        element: <Page2 />,
      },
      {
        index: true,
        element: <Page2 />,
      },
    ],
  },
]);

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")!).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
      <RouterProvider router={router} />
  </React.StrictMode>
);

Both SPA work fine but cannot go directly to the sub pages, i.e. /app/page1
What is the missing config?

I was recently looking for a solution to this as well, and came across this answer.
You can add middleware to your Vite config to do some basic URL rewriting, something like this might work for you:
const { defineConfig } = require('vite')
module.exports = defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    {
      name: 'rewrite-middleware',
      configureServer(serve) {
        serve.middlewares.use((req, res, next) => {
          if (req.url.startsWith('/app/')) {
            req.url = '/app/'
          }
          next()
        })
      }
    }
  ]
})


This is for server-side output, my app output is simple static html.

My use-case is very similar to yours - a client-side rendered React SPA with multiple HTML pages - and this config works for me when I'm running a local Vite dev server.
You'll still need to configure whichever web server you're using outside of your development environment though; you'll generally need to rewrite any requests for /app/* to go to /app/
